# The meaning of "there is no + noun"

Tags: meaning

Consider the following sentence:

> There is no bag in this room.

Which of the following (if either) could be used to say the same thing?

1. There is not a bag in this room.
2. The bag is not in this room.

Comment: That sentence exactly means, "There are no bags in this room". Another way to say it is "This room has no bags in it". It does not refer to a particular bag.

Comment: The only sentence which explains the issue is the last sentence in your explanation.

Comment: What do you think of Kate's opinion?

Comment: I can't find Kate's opinion, but knowing her, I probably agree with it. Where is it?

Comment: It's under tkp's asnwer

Comment: Yep, it's right.

Comment: But it contradicts yours.

Comment: We don't contradict each other. Kate said that *in that context*, you could say, "There's no bag in this room" to mean "It isn't in this room". That's not the same as saying the two sentences have the same meaning. They do not. Kate will agree.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that "There is no bag" doesn't mean a specific bag. But Kate says "If you were searching the house for a particular bag, you might possibly say "There's no bag in this room". She says "a particular bag. How come you don't contradict?

Comment: If you're looking for a particular bag, and you notice the room has no bags, that also means the bag you're looking for isn't there. Like, if I want some milk, and I look in the fridge, I can say, "There's no milk in the fridge" or "The fridge is empty". In that context, both sentences mean "I didn't find any milk in the fridge", but it's wrong to say those two sentences have the same literal meaning.

Comment: But Kate didn't say "There are no bags in this room" she said "There is no bag". PS: There are not two sentences in my OP. There is only one sentence and two possible meanings.

Comment: I said that "There's no bag in this room" could _possibly_ be used to express the idea that the bag someone is searching for is not there.

Comment: OK, could means that "there is no" can refer to a specific bag. Just exactly what I had suspected. It "CAN" have two meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to option #1.
*"There is not a bag in this room"* means the same as the original, *"There is no bag in this room"*.

But no to option #2.
*"The bag is not in this room."* does **not** mean the same as the original,*"There is no bag in this room"*.

The reason option #2 is not the same is that it uses the definite article -- "The" -- which means it is referring to a *particular* bag. By contrast, both the original, and option #1 are referring to *any* bag.

A way to see that is to imagine that after hearing each of the sentences, someone asks, *"Which bag?"*.

If that was asked after either the original, or option #1, the answer would be, *"Any bag!"* But it it was asked after option #2, the answer would be something like, *"The bag I told you I had lost!"* or *"The bag we've been discussing for the last ten minutes!"* etc.

---

ADDED:
Seeing the back and forth in the comments, it's clear that this question has unforeseen depths. (To which I say, "Cool!"). In pondering those depths, I found it useful to consider a different context, as follows:

Suppose a deputy detective and his boss are investigating a murder in a local office building. While the boss waits in the building foyer, the deputy goes through the entire building and gives everyone a lie detector test, but one so accurate that it enables the detective to determine the guilt or innocence of each person with 100% certainty. He then returns to the foyer, to give his report to his boss (who, it transpires, is having coffee and donuts, but that's irrelevant, if a tad annoying, especially to his long-suffering deputy ). Consider the following three options for the deputy's report:

> A. There is no murderer in this building.
>
> B. There is not a murderer in this building.
>
> C. The murderer is not in this building.

(They are, obviously, meant to be equivalent to, respectively, the original, #1, and #2 in the original post.)

The question is: do either of #B or #C mean the same as #A. Or, more precisely, the question is: CAN (or COULD) either of #B or #C mean the same as #A.

Therein lie the depths, because the answer is pretty much "well it depends". For example:

It depends on the precise meaning of "not a" in #B. If the emphasis is on the word "a" then it might be interpreted to mean the number of murderers in the building is equal to something other than one. That might, and usually would be taken to mean zero; but it could also be taken to mean two, or five, or 780!

It depends on the extent to which the meaning we are looking for concerns only the actual murderer we are hunting for. Strictly speaking, #C means only that none of the people in the building are the murderer we are hunting for. #C does not exclude the possibility that several people, perhaps even *everyone*, in the building has murdered *someone* in their life. #A, by contrast, does exclude that possibility. From that point of view, #A and #C mean two very different things. On the other hand, from the police investigation point of view, #C is *implied by* #A; that is, if #A is true then #C must be true. So from that point of view, they "can" mean the same thing.

And so on.

Good question @user1425!

Comment: Pardon me for asking. Is your native language English, It's just that you wrote "It have the same meaning as the original"

Comment: I am not sure that I clearly understand your point. Can you say it in simple words? Can "There is no bag in this room" mean "The bag is not in this room"?

Comment: If you were searching the house for a particular bag, you might possibly say "There's no bag in _this_ room" as an alternative to "It isn't in this room".

Comment: @user1425, ha! Good catch. Not only is it grammatically incorrect, it is the opposite of what I meant to say. It looks like an attempted auto-correct by the ever-interfering iOS. It "corrected" my, "It doesn't have..." to "It does. It have...". CORRECTED. Sigh. If I'd a sixpence for every time I had to fight with iOS auto-correct I'd have...well, a bunch of no-longer-valid British coins. But there would be a *lot* of them! So to answer your original question, yes English is my native language. However, being a native speaker clearly doesn't completely compensate for me being an old git! :-)

Comment: @user1425, keeping it simple then: No. "There is no bag in this room" CANNOT mean "The bag is not in this room"? The two sentences are saying different things. But there is a subtlety (which my modified answer now leaves out). But it's a logical subtlety, not really a language one.